# "it IS near your house" or "it WAS near your house"?

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

Here is the sentence:

> I don’t get how they arrange the place. You should go to the one I went to yesterday. It’s near your house.

However I am in the middle of confusion whether I should say "it’s near your house" or "it was near your house". Which one should I say and why? I think both are valid.

Comment: The 'place' is presumably still near the person's home, so there is no reason to use the past tense.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either the present or past tense. Both are perfectly acceptable and I don't even think I have a preference for either one:

> It's near your house.
>
> It was near your house.

There's a subtle difference in emphasis. With the present tense, there's more emphasis on your friend and where he lives. With the past tense, there's more emphasis on me and the trip I took yesterday to visit the place. But it's very subtle and the meaning is the same.

Comment: So basically it depends on where I want to focus. Am I correct?

Comment: You emphasize where he lives when you use the present tense. You emphasize your trip to the place if you use the past tense. But, again, it's VERY subtle.